# php encoding issue with pdf files

Tags: php, encode

Using **Ubuntu** with **php** I'm facing a common problem, to which I haven't found any solution.
I'm uploading a pdf file that I convert into text file (using ImgMagick + Tesseract).

```
    $output = shell_exec('convert -density 300 ' . $fichier . ' ' . $fichier_noExt . '.png');
    $output = shell_exec('tesseract ' . $fichier_noExt . '.png ' . $fichier_noExt . '.txt');
```

As I do this :

```
$file = fopen($fichier_txt.'.txt', 'r+');
echo $file;
```

I get some 'Â°' instead of '°', 'â‚¬ ' instead of '€' and 'Ã©' instead of 'é'.
I know it's an **encoding issue**, but I can't locate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear...

I just forgot to add this on top of my file :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

It does work now, sorry for losing your time, but I needed some fresh look :).

Have a nice day and cya !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print an UTF-8 string result,  you can try this :

```
$file = fopen($fichier_txt.'.txt', 'r+');
while(!feof($file)){
 echo mb_convert_encoding(fread($file, 1024), 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($file));
}
fclose($file);
```

**Documentation :**

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Also you can use dos2unix and mac2unix to convert file , use this custom function :

```
function convertFiles($file) { // pass complete path to file
    if (shell_exec("dos2unix $file") !== FALSE) {
        if (shell_exec("mac2unix $file") !== FALSE) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

you can install thoses command with apt-get install 
http://xmodulo.com/how-to-install-dos2unix-on-linux.html

Finally if you display it on webpage, don't forget to set meta charset content type :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

or html version

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: I tried your piece of code like this : 
fopen($file);
    while(!feof($file) && ($buffer = fgets($file, 4096) !== false))
    {
        echo mb_convert_encoding(fread($file, 1024), 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($file));
        echo '<br>';
        echo $buffer;
    }
    fclose($file);


And i still get the strange characters in my localhost output.

I tried to set_internal_encoding('UTF-8') but in vain.

When i code : echo mb_detect_encoding($file) returns me nothing...

I checked the encoding of my php file(--> ASCII), and of my text file (--> ASCII).

I'm kinda lost here !

Comment: Sorry about code in comments, but I think if i used the answer part, my post would have been deleted, so...

Comment: try to install unix command : dos2unix and mac2unix , and then execute in shell_exec before open it with php. also take a look to iconv too :)

Comment: My problem doesn't come from MAC/DOS compatibility, and I already tried with iconv, without succes... ( i still get nothing as output...)

Comment: I understood , try it before saying it doesn't work ;)

Comment: I'm gonna try this installation then, despite time is running out !

Thanks anyway for the detailled answer.

I'll keep you in touch !